# How to round button widget in Fyne golang?

Tags: go, widget, rounding, fyne

Does anyone know how to round a button widget in or any other widget in Fyne golang? Looked through the documentation can't seem find anything related to it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard widgets don’t expose the ability to tweak their graphical representation. The API is based on behaviour and outcomes rather than graphical definition.

You would need to make some sort of custom widget to build a button that does not look like a standard button.